# What do you call pastry in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, comida, sustantivos

What do you call "pastry" in Spanish? It is a name for category of food product where belongs bread, rolls etc.

I made a research already:

- *panadería* is a shop to buy bread
- *repostería*, pastelería and confitería is an art of cooking those.

But how is called the pastry itself?

Comment: The word for pastry itself could Pasteles

Comment: See this Wikipedia article for the definition of pastry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastry and note that it does not include bread or rolls.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has proposed [bollería](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bollo#Boller.C3.ADa) yet.

Comment: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3291/spanish-words-for-cake-pie-pastry-etc?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The word *pastry* translated to Spanish could be **repostería**, **pastelería** or **confitería**. Take note that *pastry* does not include breads or roll as you point.

The definition for pastry is:

> The art of preparing and decorating cakes or other desserts.

Translates to:

> El arte de preparar o decorar pasteles u otros postres.

*Panaderia* is a shop where you can buy bread and other baked products, such as *pastries*.

You can easily find this information using Wikipedia links from English to Spanish.

Comment: Where did you get that definition for pastry? Cakes are not included in pastry in most definitions.

Comment: @rsanchez https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reposter%C3%ADa You can easily switch between languages, Spanish to English. Take note that "my" definition of pastry comes from the spanish side of the word. `The art of preparing and decorating cakes or other desserts` is the literal definition of the word in spanish, so, as most translated words, its not  the specific meaning of the word in english. (sorry if i'm not being clear enough)

Comment: So you took the definition of *repostería*, translated it to Spanish, and said that's the definition for *pastry*? That's just wrong. See the article for *pastry* in English Wikipedia and you'll see a completely different definition. Or any English dictionary.